# Remove existing selected option on another Select Box

Tags: jquery, select, html5-video

My problem is that I have multiple (2 or more) select box and the selected data is from a JSON file.

It should be like this.

So, for instance I have 2 select box and the data for those select box is say 'a' and 'c'. So the Select box basically looks like this

```
<select id ="box1">
<option value='a'selected>a</option>
<option value='b'>b</option>
<option value='c'>c</option>
</select> 


<select id ="box2">
<option value='a'>a</option>
<option value='b'>b</option>
<option value='c' selected>c</option>
</select>
```

but I dont want this to happen.

I want to restrict the user from selecting option 'a' on 'box2' and vice versa, restrict the user from selecting option 'c' on 'box1'

In other words, Users can't pick 'c' on box1 and also can't pick 'a' on box2.  The only time they can pick option 'c' on box1 is if they change the selected value of box2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this could work as it basically should loop through all your selects on the page on page load and figure out what should or shouldn't be shown depending on the page load selected options.

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yps07yf5/3/

```
function checkTheDropdowns(){
  var arr  = $('select').find(':selected');
  $('select').find('option').show();
  $.each($('select'), function(){  
    var self = this;
    var selectVal = $(this).val();
    $.each(arr, function(){         
        if (selectVal !== $(this).val()){
                $(self).find('option[value="'+$(this).val()+'"]').hide()
        } else {
                $(self).find('option[value="'+$(this).val()+'"]').show()
        }
    });
 })
};
checkTheDropdowns();
$('select').on('change', checkTheDropdowns);
```

With that you should be able to change one and then it would be removed from all the rest, also it should update all when one changes.

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/yps07yf5/1/

For the first box:

```
$("#box1").on("change", function() {
  let $boxval = $("#box1").val();

  $("#box2 > option").each(function(ind) {
    let ele = $("#box2 > option").eq(ind);
    if (ele.val() === $boxval) ele.attr("disabled", "disabled");
    else ele.removeAttr("disabled");
  });
});
```

For the second box

```
 $("#box2").on("change", function() {
  let $boxval = $("#box2").val();

  $("#box1 > option").each(function(ind) {
    let ele = $("#box1 > option").eq(ind);
    if (ele.val() === $boxval) ele.attr("disabled", "disabled");
    else ele.removeAttr("disabled");
  });
})
```

Keep in mind you could absolutely optimize this to be a singular function, but I think this is clearer to give you an understanding of what is happening.

We get the box value, we then iterate over the other box' list of options, disabling the one that matches, and enabling the ones that do not match.